# Header not showing in Lightning Experience on VF Pages

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

Both in Trailhead and in a developer organization, VF Pages in Lightning Experience are not showing in the standard Lightning headers/sidebars as they do show in Salesforce Classic. Picture 1 shows the Lightning page and upon clicking Enable/Disable it opens a new tab with Page Layout Section which does not have any headers/sidebars. Picture 3 shows how Step 3 should have sidebars/headers. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Picture 1
   [image: Picture 1 - with Header/Sidebar]

Picture 2
[image: Picture 2 - Without Header/Sidebar in Lightning]

Picture 3
[image: Picture 3 - How it is supposed to show]

Comment: Are you sure your screenshots matches your question?

Comment: I think I know what Param is asking, as I've seen it too - when working in Lightning setup in a Trailhead org or DE, embedded Classic setup UIs open in a new tab or popup but are missing all of the Lightning framing elements, producing a rather confusing experience.

Comment: You described how Visualforce pages behave in Lightning Experience.
But what is the question?

Comment: @DavidReed Yes, exactly! Is there a fix to what David mentioned?