# Each click on salesforce opens in a new tab

Tags: configuration, setup

I can't find where in the setup I may have done something wrong,
But each time I try openning something (object description, records, ..) it opens in a new tab, and in this new tab on the left there isn't the habitual side display

It should be easy to rectify, but it sure is very anooying !
Any ideas where to setup it right ?

[image]

Comment: For context, a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251635/header-not-showing-in-lightning-experience-on-vf-pages) that I think got closed before it was fully understood. I've repeatedly experienced the same issue and don't have a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it **seems** that it's a plugin I installed, called Ghostery !

I deactivated it, and salesforce seems to behave as usual.
If someone could confirm it was the cause, and why, I'll be happy to hear explainations !

[image]